Trying to change java versions inside of gitlab-ci.yml
I am attempting to change the java version in our gitlab-ci.yml by changing the JAVA_HOME to our java 11 jdk. In checking to see if it worked, I am running
java -version
javac -version

to check if it worked. Strangely the java version is returning as Java 17 (the most recent version installed for gitlab runners. The javac on the other hand is showing as Java 8, so I'm quite confused about that and don't want any false positives on building through our pipeline.
Here is our current yaml:
variables:
  FF_USE_FASTZIP: "true"
  ARTIFACT_COMPRESSION_LEVEL: "fast"
  CACHE_COMPRESSION_LEVEL: "fast"
  GIT_STRATEGY: clone
  GIT_CLEAN_FLAGS: none
  CENTRAL_CONFIG_BRANCH: main
  MAVEN_OPTS: >-
    -Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository
    -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true
    -Djava.awt.headless=true

.dependencies_cache:
  cache:
    key: "$CI_JOB_NAME-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
    paths:
      - .m2/repository

stages:
  - build

before_script:
  - export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk"

maven-compile:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - <>
  script:
    - ./run -b
    - java -version
    - javac -version 
  except:
      - tags

Any thoughts or advice on what might be happening would be great. Thank you

Edit your gitlab-cy.yml like this:
variables:
  JAVA_HOME: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk"
before_script:
  export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
